# What is the best way to send large data from WCF service to Client?

Tags: wcf, streaming, mtom

I have a particular service which returns large amount of data.  What' is the best practice and options available in WCF to handle this?

These large data is returned after doing all the filtering, so no more filtering is possible.
The data could go into GB's.  I do understand there is a limit to how much data a system can handle.

But give the above scenario what options/alternatives would you recommend.

Answer (score 4):

Use streaming [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**MTOM** is a mechanism for transmitting large binary attachments with SOAP messages as raw bytes, allowing for smaller messages.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395209.aspx for details.